# Asp.net calendar control: how do you make events to Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, calendar

I have an question for a project in my company.
I need to make a calendar for a school college,
with this feature: add datum with a comment that needs to be saved into an SQL database.
It must be viewed into the ASP.NET calendar control.

This is my current code in `Calender.aspx.cs`. If you need the markup code, let me know. Please help me get a clear idea of the structure behind the code, I think I'm not on the right track.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    Hashtable events = null; 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Stefan"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Berichten (date, timestamp, commentheader, commentsub) values (@date, @timestamp, @commentheader, @commentsub)", con))
        {
            DateTime date = 
            string date = TextDate.DateTime(TextDate).ToString() : "";
            string commenttop = TextComment.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@commentheader", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = commenttop;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@commentsub", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = commentsub;


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            events = new Hashtable();
        }
}
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string eventDate = TextDate.Text.Trim();
            string eventTitle = TextComment.Text.Trim();

            events.Add(eventDate, eventTitle);
        }
    }
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `@timestamp` parameter being added

Answer (score 0):

add parameter of timestamp

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextDate;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@commentheader", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = commenttop;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@commentsub", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = commentsub;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@timestamp", System.Data.SqlDbType.datetime).Value = YOURTIMESTAMPVALUE;
```